# Can I use Webform CiviCRM Integration to always create a new contact?

Tags: webform-civicrm

For a specific project we are using the Webform CiviCRM Integration extension for a form where the website visitor can sign a petition. Once this is done we want to use specific matching to find a contact or create a new one (using the apiWrapper hook).
This means I would like an option in Webform CiviCRM Integration to say that it should always create a contact and NOT try to find a matching one using the dedupe rules, is that possible?

(using CiviCRM 4.6.13 with Drupal 7.41)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am not sure that I understand the question.

If you want every submission to create a contact without checking for an existing contact in CiviCRM, don't you do that by selecting **-None-** for the Matching Rule for contact 1.

Comment: I think JoAnne is right - we don't have to come up with anything crazy that will never find a match!

Comment: That is probably what I was looking for, but at my customer's site the is no Matching Rule question for contact 1. They must be using an old version of webform civicrm integration

Comment: That is indeed the case, they needed to upgrade their Webform and Webform CiviCRM integration installation

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried creating a crazy dedupe rule - and selecting that for your contacts in the webform_civicrm tab for each contact - a rule that is such that webform civicrm can never ever find a mattch?

Comment: That could certainly work :-) My initial solution now is ignoring webform_civicrm and creating my own module that picks up the webform submission and calls a specific api.

Comment: Ok that's crazy :-)